# Adding Click Event on background-color Not Set

Tags: javascript

Looking at event handlers in [Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja](http://www.manning.com/resig/), the following code sets up events for either the DOM or IE model:

```
if(document.addEventListener) {
    console.log("document.addEventListener");
    this.addEvent = function(elem, type, fn) {              
        elem.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
        return fn;
    };

    this.removeEvent = function(elem, type, fn) {
        elem.removeEventListener(type, fn, false);
    };
}

// [IE code elided]
```

Then, the book shows an example of how to add and remove an event:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) (function(elem) {
    var handler = addEvent(elem, "click", function() { 
        this.style.backgroundColor = 
            this.style.backgroundColor == "" ? "green" : "";                    
        removeEvent(elem, "click", handler);
    });
})(elems[i]);
```

When clicking the `Good Morning` `<div>` (which has a `background-color: red`), why does the `add green background-color` event still fire?

http://jsfiddle.net/c9Mq3/

Comment: It only fires cause you're clicking on it. Nothing to do with the background color you set.

Comment: However I would not expect the `background-color` for `Good Morning` (since it's set to `red`) to turn to `green`. I would've expected this code-block, `this.style.backgroundColor = 
            this.style.backgroundColor == "" ? "green" : "";`, to return `""`.

Comment: You set your background color through CSS class. `this.style` refers to inline style.

Comment: Thanks, @FlorianF. Removing my CSS, and then adding `<div id="gm" style="background-color:red;">Good Morning</div>` resulted in behavior that I expected. (http://jsfiddle.net/c9Mq3/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reposting comments as answer for eventual future reference :

Background turns green even if it already has a background color defined because it is set in a CSS class while `this.style` only refers to inline style.

Settings it through inline style produces [the result you expect](http://jsfiddle.net/c9Mq3/1/).

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) (function(elem) {
    var handler = addEvent(elem, "click", function() { 
        this.style.backgroundColor = 
            this.style.backgroundColor == "" ? "green" : "";                    
        removeEvent(elem, "click", handler);
    });
})(elems[i]);
```

Loops through all elements, and adds a "click" event listener.

The event still fires (and the colour changes), because the listener is removed after the code that changes the background colour.

This is the code that runs when you click on an element:

```
this.style.backgroundColor = this.style.backgroundColor == "" ? "green" : "";                    
removeEvent(elem, "click", handler);
```

Set colour first, then remove the event listener.

Comment: So the listener is added **before** the DOM reflects `Good Morning`'s `background-color` of `red`? It's basically a race, then, that the `add event` wins?

Comment: @KevinMeredith: The event listener is added when the page loads. It doesn't matter what colour the div is, then.
When you click a element, __that__ element is set to green, __then__ the listener on __that__ element is removed.

Comment: @KevinMeredith: Also, the reason the red div turns green is because the javascript "set to green" overrides the red style.

Comment: But isn't my issue what Florian explained - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20842523/adding-click-event-on-background-color-not-set/20842641?noredirect=1#comment31262031_20842523?